# appendChiled print more times than expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a problem in my `react.js` app. I have this class in my controller.js file:

```
class Render {

renderSideBar(sidbar_background, sidebar_text_color, li_data) {
    const body = document.querySelector("body");
    const aside = document.createElement("aside");
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    aside.style.background = sidbar_background;
    aside.style.color = sidebar_text_color;
    aside.id = "sidebar";
    ul.style.listStyle = "none";
    ul.classList.add("sidebar__ul");
    body.appendChild(aside);
    aside.appendChild(ul);

    for (let i = 0; i < li_data.length;i++) {
        a.innerHTML = li_data[i][0];
        a.href = li_data[i][1];
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(a);

    }

    return false;


}
 }
export default Render;
```

and i have this code in my App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import Render from './controller';

const build = new Render();

function App() {
    return (build.renderSideBar("#0275d8\n","white", [
        ['Home', '/'],
        ['home', '/']
    ]));
}

export default App;
```

The problem is, when I open my page, I have 2 of `"aside"` with same child elements and I expected it to be just 1 `"aside"`, not 2.

Anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You are appending the same element. An element can only live in one place

Comment: @epascarello what you mean ??

Comment: `const li = document.createElement("li");
    const a = document.createElement("a");` has to be inside the loop

Comment: Also it is odd you would be using React and building the menu this way.

Comment: I wonder why you are using React if you are making your html in a function? Why not your side bar a simple react component?

Comment: @SanishJoseph i just need to train js so i did this

Comment: @epascarello i did what you said and still got 2 aside

Comment: @epascarello when i only use body.appendChild(aside) i also got 2 aside

Comment: Well my guess is the rendereing code is fired more than one time.

Comment: @epascarello i only used my function in App.js

Comment: Does not mean React is not calling it more than once.... Add a console.log..... See what happens ;) `console.log('hello', Date.now());`

Comment: @epascarello in console i only got 1 result

Comment: @epascarello i also tried other element  and same result i got 2

Comment: Can you return null instead of false? App is a react functional component and its expecting some jsx or null.

Comment: @SanishJoseph same

Comment: 99.9% sure if you have two of the same elements, you be running than code more than once. I am 99.999% sure you should not be doing this anyway. Sort of like opeing a window with a hammer, works, but there is a better way to open it.

Comment: @epascarello i think i found the solution i used setInterval to check if page is loaded or no and it works i got only 1 aside

Comment: So what you are saying is it is called more than once.....

Comment: @epascarello see what i answered in this question

Comment: It's created only once when I copied your code. It worked as you expected without any code change. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xkonmu I just got 1 link though !!

Comment: @SanishJoseph in my dev server it created 2 idk why but i fixed it you can see my answer

Comment: Your link creation logic is wrong btw. Moved  const a = document.createElement('a'); and li creation to the loop. Good luck with ur learnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution i used setInterval function outside App function to check if page is loaded or no and than cleared the interval the code should be like this:

```
let interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
        clearInterval(interval);
        build.renderSideBar("#0275d8\n","white", [
            ['Home', '/'],
            ['home', '/'],
            ['home', '/'],
        ])
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: So you reinvented DOMContentLoaded?

Comment: @epascarello idk what are you talking about but i made this "Interval" run when document status is complete

Comment: because there is a DOMContentLoaded event that triggers when the readyState changes

Comment: @epascarello i didn't edit DOMContentLoaded event i made a new "interval" in App.js under imports lines and build const so that will run only 1 time when document is ready

Comment: I am saying.... DOMContentLoaded is what you should be using instead of setTimeout....